# Cascade deletes in Redis

Tags: redis, nosql, cascade

On my current project I'm implementing autocompletion service on top of Redis, for it I use such approach ([this article](https://thorstenball.com/blog/2012/06/08/search-autocompletion-with-redis/) describes it more widely):

1) for storing dump of the data I have hash in which I put searchable objects as a values, for instance

```
HSET data 1 "{\"name\":\"Kill Bill\",\"year\":2003}"
HSET data 2 "{\"name\":\"King Kong\",\"year\":2005}"
```

2) for storing all possible sequences of input characters (that I generate in advance) which could be used in search I use sorted sets, like

```
ZADD search:index:k 0 1
ZADD search:index:ki 0 1
ZADD search:index:kil 0 1
ZADD search:index:kill 0 1
```

Where value stored in sorted set (in my example '1') is key for data from hash. So, for searching some data (for example where name started with 'ki') we need to make two steps:

```
data_keys = REDIS.zrevrange('search:index:ki', 0, -1)
matching_data = REDIS.hmget(data, *data_keys)
```

The issue I tried to solve - how automatically remove all data from sorted sets related to hash values when I removed it? In relational databases I can use cascade deletion for such cases, but how can I handle it in Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design appears awkward to me, I'm unsure what you're actually trying to do with Redis and perhaps that could be the topic of another question.

That said, to address your question, Redis does offer a "cascading delete"-like behavior. Instead, if you're deleting hash "1", iterate the prefix and `ZREM` it from the relevant sorted sets.

Note: do not use a Lua script for this task, as it will generate key names (i.e. sorted sets by prefix) and that is against the recommendations (will not work on a cluster)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As for common approach - you can see the article I mentioned in the question, there are more details why it is done this way.

Comment: The article has somewhat aged ;) Nowadays, lexicographical ranges are a better choice, not to mention http://redisearch.io that does that and much more (disclosure: affiliated)

Comment: I need to look on lexicographical ranges & redisearch, thank you!